# Sun Metro WebServices with Spring

Tags: sun, java-metro-framework

I am using sun metro webservice stack with spring. every thing is working fine but i am unable customize namespace of the my service. my service always setting  namespace  as   {http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}. how do i customize my namespace for my service?

Answer (score 0):

after my research i know i missing namespace for my service. so it takes default spring bean name space. so we need to add  namespace to service as show in example.